# Why is 18.04 LTS not booting after installation?

Tags: boot, nvidia

After several attempts at installation, I finally got 18.04 to boot on a live DVD and finally got it to install. However, after rebooting to boot from HDD, it hangs up after a long wait (like 6 hours) sitting at the Ubuntu logo. My machine is an i9 7960x with 128GB RAM, two Nvidia Titan P graphics cards, and a 6TB HDD. Is this too much machine for 18.04 LTS? BTW, I swapped out the HDD with an older 80GB HDD that had a 16.04 LTS install and the machine booted just fine. Why is 18.04 LTS struggling to install and boot?

Comment: Did you verify your download of 18.04 LTS? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) or check the install media prior to installation (using the option at the first menu before the try/install second menu)? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck but note this menu needs a key to appear & looks very different to the pictures in this wiki)  Assuming you did the checks, have you tried using 'nomodeset' in case it's video related...

Comment: Yes, I did verify to download, following the instructions for all the good that did. It came back with BAD ... and the instructions only said that I need to add the trusted site, whatever the author meant by that ... add to what?

Comment: There was definitely a video problem, so I booted to live DVD, which did not have a video problem. Straight install does not work with the video cards. Nvidia has drivers for these cards, but I have to get the system up before I can download them.

Comment: The SHA256SUMS do not match the iso file, so apparently they are not keeping the SHA256SUMS up to date with releases of the iso files. I've downloaded the iso file multiple times and they all fail the SHA256SUMS test. However, some worked and some didn't, so I've wasted a few R/W DVDs finding out.

Comment: If your checks came back 'BAD' - I would work on fixing that first with another download & write to media first.  I'd only worry about fixing video issues if you can know the install is trustworthy.  The minutes it takes to validate download & media save hours-days of install-problem-validation...

Comment: The SHA256 sums are valid & tested/updated - I'd validate your sha256sum tool, or download from a different source & to a different box through a different network - as the checksums are correct.  (myself I download iso from local mirror, but usually check md5sum/sha256 sources from main site on different box thru different gateway).  *I would also check your machine for malware!*

Comment: OK, how does one go about getting SHA256SUMS and iso files that actually match. I installed FreeBSD 11.0 on this machine, just to check to see if the hardware had any problems. FreeBSD installs just fine. Then I went back and formatted the disk to start over with Ubuntu and that is when I got the Live DVD to boot. How do you propose that I fix the iso integrity? The tutorial you point to is the very one that I used to verify ... download 20 times or more? Nothing changes ... are the Ubuntu servers sketchy?

Comment: My machines do not have malware, Norton protected. scanned regularly and besides, I downloaded the file and checked the SHA256SUMS on an older Ubuntu 16.04 machine. The sha256sums tool that I used was downloaded according to the tutorial that you pointed to. Is there a way to test that too for integrity?

Comment: It won't be the servers, you have either bad software that check sha256sum (*why I mentioned the bad mac software [port] that gives wrong results to every other tool but itself*), have a bad network (mitm attack etc) or malware on your machine changing image on save  - i'd suspect the first myself...  Having nortons or another low-quality malware protection doesn't mean much, they help stop some malware, but cannot detect most infections already on the machine, and provide no protection for malware when it's new (or newly re-engineered) - it's mostly false security for profit. Use another box

Comment: What other sites are there to download from. The main Ubuntu web site is where I downloaded from?

Comment: Use a different tool to download.  I'd `wget` the file myself (or more likely use `zsync` to reduce bandwidth) & not download from a browser.  Was the 16.04 install on hardware? or saving on a foreign device (nfs or other server) or host (in which case i think malware issue again).   As for mirrors - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors  (cd image list)

Comment: Do Ubuntu machines get malware on them? I downloaded, as I mentioned above, on a 16.04 LTS Ubuntu machine.

Comment: If your Ubuntu 16.04(.6) LTS machine is up-to-date, and you didn't download using a browser you should get a valid file (assuming safe network, no mitm etc).  If you use a browser, add-ons for the browser can be as infected almost as easily as the same add-ons on a windows box (why I download using wget/zsync/.. tools & not from browser; let alone the extra abilities other tools provide like zsync) and why I mentioned that specifically.

Comment: OK, I used wget on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine (that is up to date) to download another image. Ran through the verification process with SHA256SUMS and this time everything verified with GOOD and OK. Burned the DVD with this image and went through the installation process again. This time ... I got the same result. Won't boot after installation. It starts the boot with the UBUNTU logo, then goes into a mode of hitting the disk with short bursts and the screen goes blank. I've had 18.04 working on lesser machines and I've had FreeBSD 11.0 working on this machine, so this makes no sense

Comment: OK, if the OEM install is used, it works. The install to disk boots properly. Normal install still fails to boot from HDD after install. Does this offer a clue?